# Escaping strings in bash

Tags: bash

I have this simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
isRunning=$(ps -Af | awk '{if ($11 == "HomeDir") { print $0 }}' | wc -l)
if [ $isRunning == "0" ]; then
    echo "Script is running"
fi
```

The script returns:

```
./script.sh: line 3: [ 0: command not found
```

What did i do wrong?

Comment: Aside from the obvious, if you are going to the trouble of piping the output ftom `ps` to awk, you might as well rewrite the awk script to print something sensible and useful, and avoid the silly `wc -l`. More on the venerable [UUCA diatribe page][1].

[1] http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to simplify:

```
if [ -n "$(ps -Af | awk '$11 == "HomeDir"')" ]; then echo "running"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `if` to:

```
if [ "$isRunning" -eq "0" ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

The `test` operator for equality is `=`, not `==`. Also, take the custom to surround variables by `"` just in case:

```
if [ "$isRunning" = "0"] ; then ...
```

or just use `-eq`, as codaddict suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You are using bash so I think "==" is totally ok:
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

```
$ [ a == b ]
$ echo $?
1
$ [ a == a ]
$ echo $?
0
```

I run your script on my machine but I didn't get your error. My bash version is 4.1_p9. You could also try [[ foo == bar ]] and it should be working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do u need a script for thsi?
simple command will be enough.

```
ps -Af | awk '{if ($11 == "HomeDir"){counter++}END{if(counter>0)print "script is running"}}'
```

Comment: ps -Af | grep -q -E '^([^ ]+ +){10}HomeDir ' && echo "Script is running" is even more simple :)